# Where has the normal Energy Saving mode gone in Nougat?

Tags: 7.0-nougat, samsung-galaxy-s-6

When I had Android 6 on my Galaxy S6, the quick options drawer had two different symbols for saving energy: *Normal* and *Extreme*. *Normal* regulated background apps and dimmed the screen a bit, but wasn't too noticeable; *Extreme* turned off any themes and didn't let me start most apps.

After update to Android 7, there is only one such symbol left in the options drawer, and tapping it leads to a dialog "Maximum energy saving mode" which basically does what *Extreme* did before.

Now, how do I enable or disable the *Normal* energy saving mode?

Answer (score 0):

The battery saving button in the quick options tray enables the energy saving option that was last chosen in *Settings -> Device Maintenance -> Battery*.